# Camel Rest to dB Query, returning incorrect response

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-sql

I am trying to receive a xml message from a rest call, then make a call to the db, map each row into an object and then return the complete marshalled object as the rest response.

However my db query result is being returned as the rest response even before the last process has executed. Can you please advise if there is something wrong I am doing that is resulting in the dB query being returned?

Please also advise if my solution is the correct approach, As the real db query will have about 25000 lines and I am worried my web service times out.

Route:

```java
        from("jetty://http://localhost:8888/...")
                .log("Message Received")
                .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
                .unmarshal(soapMessage)
                .removeHeaders("CamelHttp")
                .to("direct:ProcessRequest");

        from("direct:ProcessRequest")
           .setBody(constant("SELECT * FROM table"))
           .to("jdbc:dataSource").split(body()).parallelProcessing()
           .process(rowProcessor)
           .aggregate(constant(true), new ArrayListAggregationStrategy())
            .completionFromBatchConsumer()
            .process(combinedProcess)
```

rowProcessor

```java
        RowResult rowResult = new RowResult();

        Map<String, Object> row = exchange.getIn().getBody(Map.class);
        System.out.println("Processing " + row);
        rowResult.setName((String) row.get("name"));
        rowResult.setSurname((String) row.get("surname"));

        exchange.getIn().setBody(responserowResultDetail);
```

combinedProcess

```java
        System.out.println("Bulk process");
        People people = new People();

        List<rowResult>  rowResults = (List<rowResult>)exchange.getIn().getBody();

        people.getEveryone().addAll(rowResults);


        exchange.getIn().setBody(people);
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
```

I am getting the following from rest response:

```
[{id=1, name = test ...... }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your `direct:ProcessRequest` thread is doing exactly what it should do - i.e. it is returning what went into the split as you've not got an aggregation strategy linked to the split. What I think you need to do is get the split to do the aggregation, and then it will work. I've not tested this, but I think you need something like this:

```
    from("direct:ProcessRequest")
       .setBody(constant("SELECT * FROM table"))
       .to("jdbc:dataSource")
       .split(body(), new ArrayListAggregationStrategy() )
           .parallelProcessing()
           .process(rowProcessor)
       .end()
       .completionFromBatchConsumer()
       .process(combinedProcess)
```

Comment: My aggregation works. However my issue is the response that gets sent back to rest call is the list returned by db query and not the body i set in combinedProcess

Comment: The issue is that if you don't specify the aggregation strategy in the split, then the split returns the original message it receives. Hence, what it being returned from `direct:ProcessRequest` to `from("jetty...` is the original message passed into the splitter. See https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/split-eip.html#_split_aggregate_requestreply_sample in the documentation for splitter.