# Camel Rest DSL returns an iterator?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am confused as to why the following code returns an iterator from a POST request, rather than a JSON. I would appreciate understanding where I went wrong and why this happens.

Code:

```
@Component
public class
Route extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    protected void configure() throws Exception {

        CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat()
                .setTrim(true)
                .setLazyLoad(true)
                .setUseMaps(true);

        rest("/")
                .post().consumes("text/csv").produces("application/json")
                .route()
                .unmarshal(csv)
                .split(body()).streaming().parallelProcessing()
                .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson, true)
                .end()
```

The return value is `org.apache.camel.dataformat.csv.CsvUnmarshaller$CsvIterator@1b27abe7` and I would expect a JSON.

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57671284/camel-rest-to-db-query-returning-incorrect-response. Split returns the original exchange unless you provide it with an aggregation strategy. See https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/split-eip.html#_what_the_splitter_returns.

Comment: Thank you @Screwtape Do you have any advise on managing large workloads? Presumably I could aggregate batches?

Comment: I don't. I've no idea how you could return batches to a REST query anyway? I assume the client is expecting a single return, unless you get it to specify a callback rest service in which case you'd not be returning the data via the original rest call anyway.